# Configuring Shiro with Guice without a ServletContext

Tags: java, apache, jetty, guice, shiro

I'm using *Guice* to wire a *Jetty* server and I want to add some security with *Apache Shiro*.

It seems Shiro needs a *ServletContext* to be configured, but the problem is I don;t have a ServletContext at the configuration time (for example in a *ServletModule* as the documentation states). The *ServletContext* is available in *GuiceServletContextListener*, but at this time, my injector is already created so it's to late to install the *Shiro* module.

I tried to provide the *ServletContext* to *Shiro* through a *Guice* provider, (*Provider<ServletContext>*) but still without success. I thought this provider will serve the ServletContext after its creation. This also gives a WARNING:

```
"com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule$BackwardsCompatibleServletContextProvider get
WARNING: You are attempting to use a deprecated API (specifically, attempting to @Inject ServletContext inside an eagerly created singleton. While we allow this for backwards compatibility, be warned that this MAY have unexpected behavior if you have more than one injector (with ServletModule) running in the same JVM."
```

How could one install the Shiro Web module after the injector is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to get the ServletContext is to extend the `GuiceServletContextListener`.

Imho a major oversight of the API.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=603

There is also a tutorial here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-320

(Edit: after reading comments)
You have 2 options:

1. Refacture code to only create the injector in `GuiceServletContextListener`
2. Use a child injector (tricky)

With Child Injector only instances created by the child injector will get the "Shiroed". Keep in mind: Just-in-time bindings created for child injectors will be created in an ancestor injector whenever possible.

Things will work as expected for your Servlets and Filters but if you have business logic in your already created Injector they will not see Shiro. You can workaround this in a couple ways...

Comment: In my case, the injector is already created by the time the ServletContext is initialized in the GuiceServletContextListener.

Comment: In Guice, the ServletContext is needed in WebGuiceEnvironment. I tried to modify the WebGuiceEnvironment and set the ServletContext after the injector creation, but it doesn;t seem to work like this either. The request is blocked, but my Realm is not asked for authorizations (that means everything is blocked everytime)

Comment: Can you add a module to existing Injector? How do you create it?

Comment: Injector creation is the first thing the application does. That's why I say is too late to create the injector in the  GuiceServletContextListener. After the injector is created, as far as I know, it's not possible to add other modules (unless with child injectors - already tried, doesn't work in this case)

Comment: I'd add the regular ShiroModule in your Application Injector, and then add the WebShiroModule (modified to remove the bindings already included in the ShiroModule). This should cover all the angles.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the solutions that I also found. It seems to work ,but you have to modify the ShiroWebModule (together with the hole web package) yourself. I already talked with the shiro guys and created a Jira Issue about this problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-401. So sometime in the future it should be possible to install the ShiroWebModule without the ServletContext.

Comment: Here is the thread on Apache forum: http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Why-is-Shiro-assuming-that-you-already-have-a-server-running-tt7578017.html

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and using the info from @Mircea all I did was cast the GuiceServletContextLister to ServletContext  in other words

Guice.createInjector(new ShiroWebModule((ServletContext)this);

hopes this helps